# How do you defeat the three enemies at the start of EX Stage 2 Ryukyu Beach in Cladun Returns?

Tags: cladun

In EX Stage 2, Ryukyu Beach, of Cladun Returns: This is Sengoku!, there are three enemies at the very start that must be defeated to unlock the doors. Without these doors unlocked no further progress can be made in the stage.

From what I can tell, these enemies cannot be attacked from the front by any weapons. Sickles do not seem to go past them, so they can't hit them on the return journey. Magic attacks are blocked by them.

These enemies appear in other stages, but can usually be baited out and attacked from behind. However here they appear to stand in place, no matter what.

What weapon/job/skill must be used to defeat these three enemies so that the gate can be unlocked?